# MYSQL - get list of items within in a group that do not fail a condition test

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to come up with a query that will only select a servername that doesn't have a workstation in a state of 2.

In other words, if a VM server has an associated vwks with a state of 2 then I don't want that server as part of the output.  I only want a list of servers that only have vwks in a state of 1 as I'm trying to determine which vm servers are "free" or open.  If a vwks has a state of 2 then it is in currently some build stage so that entire server needs to be ignored.

Data

```
WKS    Server     state
----------------------- 
vwks1   svr1       1
vwks2   svr2       1 
vwks3   svr3       2
vwks4   svr1       2
vwks5   svr2       1
```

Desired Output (only svr2 doesn't have a vwks that isn't in a state of 2).

```
  Server
  ------
   svr2
```

Have to apply this across thousands of workstations and servers.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY server` and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT server
FROM tablename
GROUP BY server
HAVING SUM(state = 2) = 0
```

Comment: That's a clever solution !

Answer (score 1):

you can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  `WKS` VARCHAR(5),
  `Server` VARCHAR(4),
  `state` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO test
  (`WKS`, `Server`, `state`)
VALUES
  ('vwks1', 'svr1', 1),
  ('vwks2', 'svr2', 1),
  ('vwks3', 'svr3', 2),
  ('vwks4', 'svr1', 2),
  ('vwks5', 'svr2', 1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Server`
FROM test t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM test t2 WHERE `state` = 2 AND t1.`Server` = t2.`Server`
);
```

**Output**

```
| Server |
| ------ |
| svr2   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ecsfcNWXFBB2gorirJL6L4/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Server
FROM <Relation>
WHERE Server NOT IN (
    SELECT Server
    FROM <Relation>
    WHERE state = 2)
```

Just insert your relation name in `<Relation>`.